# dotcover/opencover link coverage to other assembly than test-assembly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, opencover, dotcover, reportgenerator

I have divided my source code and tests in separate solutions for **C#**.
In my tests I create **link** to the actual code and **implement** stub-implementations for its dependencies where I can't mock the implementation.

If I run *opencover* or *dotcover* to get the coverage of the unit-tests and genreate a report with *reportgenerator* it groups the coverage per test assembly, however i want to map this coverage to the actual source code/assembly (from which i linked my file) in my resulting report.

Is there any way, in **opencover** or **dotcover**, to map my code coverage results with the actual code (and exclude my stub-classes that don't map with the code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by running a small script before generating the actual report. This script replaces the *ModuleName* in the XML of the coverage result by **OpenCover** with the assembly of my production code.

**ReportGenerator** will then nicely merge all my results into a single report.